# How to make add to favorites button using share preferences but without any database in android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating toggle button for add to favorite feature using shared preferences but its not working when I'm clicking on button for add to favorites its working but when I moved back to another activity and comes back to this activity my button is not checked and when I'm clicking again its saying removed from favorites but it should be marked favorite because I already marked it as favorite

**XML**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BenefitDescriptionActivity">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/favouritetogglebuttonID"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/benefitdescriptionscrollviewID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/benefitimageviewID" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import static android.text.Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT;

public class BenefitDescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ToggleButton favouriteToggleButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_benefit_description);

        favouriteToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.favouritetogglebuttonID);
        favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
        favouriteToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isFavourite = readstate();
                if (isFavourite) {                 favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this,"Added to favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isFavourite = false;
                    savestate(isFavourite);
                }
                else {
                    favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this,"Removed from favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isFavourite = true;
                    savestate(isFavourite);
                }
            }
        });

    private void savestate(boolean isFavourite){
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences.edit();
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State",isFavourite);
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.apply();
    }
    private boolean readstate(){
        SharedPreferences asharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return asharedPreferences.getBoolean("State",true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the return of readstate() ? Is it returning proper value when you come back to toggle activity?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not setting the value stored when you return to the activity. You need to check and set it in `onResume`. Also change your code in `onClickListener` like this:

```
  favouriteToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isFavourite = readstate();
                    if (!isFavourite) {                 favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                        Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this,"Added to favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isFavourite = true;
                        savestate(isFavourite);
                    }
                    else {
                        favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
                        Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this,"Removed from favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isFavourite = false;
                        savestate(isFavourite);
                    }
                }
            });


        }
        private void savestate(boolean isFavourite){
            SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences.edit();
            aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State",isFavourite);
            aSharedPreferencesEdit.apply();
        }
        private boolean readstate(){
            SharedPreferences asharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return asharedPreferences.getBoolean("State",false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            boolean isFavourite = readstate();
            Log.e("main","value = " + isFavourite);
            if (!isFavourite) {
                favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
            }
            else {
                favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
            }
        }
```

Comment: on first click it shows removed from favorits (which is already empty)

Comment: also i have press twice to get the toast  note i have been using button not toggle and it is not even saving the result

Answer (score 1):

You always put a fixed background to your favouriteToggleButton, you need to read your SharedPreferences State value and set a background to your favouriteToggleButton, just add these lines to your activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (! readstate()) {
            favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
        }
        else {
            favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting

```
    favouriteButton.setChecked(true);   //or false depending
```

in you onClickListener

Answer (score -1):

I have added some comment in the code, these may help your app perform better.

And in the code you can replace AsyncTask with another tools.

Just prevent do the IO job in UI thread.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class BenefitDescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ToggleButton favouriteToggleButton;
    private boolean favourite = false;
    private CheckAsyncTask task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_benefit_description);

        favouriteToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.favouritetogglebuttonID);
        favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
        favouriteToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //use a variable, not read file every time click
                if (favourite) {
                    favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                    Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this, "Added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favourite = false;
                    savestate(favourite);
                } else {
                    favouriteToggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
                    Toast.makeText(BenefitDescriptionActivity.this, "Removed from favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favourite = true;
                    savestate(favourite);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //when activity visible, read boolean value from file and set button state
        if (task == null) {
            task = new CheckAsyncTask(favouriteToggleButton);
        }
        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //stop task when activity invisible, prevent memory leak
        if (task != null) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    // you also can execute savestate in a background thread
    private void savestate(boolean isFavourite) {
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences.edit();
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.apply();
    }

    private static class CheckAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private WeakReference<ToggleButton> buttonWeakReference;

        public CheckAsyncTask(ToggleButton button) {
            buttonWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(button);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //do you read file job in background thread may perform better
            if (buttonWeakReference.get() != null) {
                SharedPreferences asharedPreferences = buttonWeakReference.get().getContext().getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                favorite = asharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
                return favorite;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            //got read file result set Button state in UI thread
            if (aBoolean && buttonWeakReference != null && buttonWeakReference.get() != null) {
                buttonWeakReference.get().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying we need to use an `AsyncTask` everytime activity is resumed, we get value from sharedpref?

Comment: @sanjeev Not totally, using `AsyncTask` just want to do the IO operation in background thread. put the read logic in onResume() just a example, you can put it in the `onCreate()`, `onPostCreate()`, `onCreateView()` after the button created